# What does {block:HomePage} of Tumblr do?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-html

I tried a lot of keywords on Google but all of them was misunderstand with `{block:IndexPage}`. So what is true color of `{block:HomePage}`. And what is difference between it and `{block:IndexPage}`?

[Tumblr Custom Theme document](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#basic_variables) is so poor. It doesn't explain detail about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{block:HomePage} is only the home page (blog.tumblr.com/)

{block:IndexPage} includes pages like blog.tumblr.com/tagged/tag & blog.tumblr.com/search/query.